# How to prevent marksdwarfes from suicides?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My current fort has line of fortifications and line of floor built of top of the wall. Floor built on top of constructed fortifications.
Markdswarfs are stationed behind fortifications on `f`loor inside and should shoot siegers outside.

```
  z-1       z      z+1
,,W,,,   ·fF···   ··f···
,,W,g,   ·fF···   ··f···
,,W,,,   ·fF···   ··f···

, - ground
W - wall
g - sieger
f - floor
F - fortification
· - empty space
```

However several times I found one of my dwarfs outside. I suspect, that he somehow got through fortifications.

There is reported bug: [0008160: Creatures can jump through fortifications](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=8160)

Is there way to prevent my marksdwarfs from passing through fortifications?

Answer (score 2):

Your dwarfs maybe Jumping/Dodging through the fortifications when fighting. One possible way to stop this would be to do a double layer of fortifications ( So fFF.) From what I understand of the bug report they'll only travel 1 layer deep into the fortifications when dodging and hopefully the same will be true when jumping. Once they are 'inside' the fortification it no longer exists from their view point, so they could fall outside the wall previously possibly by dodging again (and ending up over open air).

A double layer of fortifications will stop them moving further 'out' and instead the only direction they can choose to dodge/jump in is back toward the floor tiles.

Comment: This will require extensive training of archers, before they will be able to shoot through 2 fortifications. And my only elite marksdwarf just jumped through fortification :(

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add note about training/difficulties added by shooting.

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with using traffic zones to make the fortification and the square beyond Forbidden with a value of 100.  I saw a reference to this technique on the forums.

Comment: Do they obey during seiges tho? The worst bit being they can jump through them.... so even if they aren't walking on the forbidden area, does it help? (The jump is in reaction to an attack, i don't think it cares where they land).